# Tikz - dynamic letter

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I've got the task, to create a pattern for a letter or something else. It must have a perspective view like in this example

[image: Example]

So I think I've just managed to create something that looks nearly similar to this example.

The Question:

Do you know any possibility to create the background (the outer lines of the letter, the lower left corner and the shadows) in a way, that it grows, when you type in more lines, or other stuff, and it automatically shrinks, when you have less things on the page?

Here is the code for the things I already have.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{
            arrows,
            shapes,
            shadows.blur,
            positioning,
            calc,
            intersections,
            decorations.text,
            backgrounds,
            plotmarks,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=0.2, every node/.style={xslant=0.05, transform shape}, scale=0.9, font=\small]
\fill [color=black!20!white,opacity=0.5] (0.15,-0.15) rectangle (15.15,-20.15);
\draw [color=black!30, fill=white] (0,0) -- (15,0) -- (15,-20) -- (7.3,-20) arc (270:220:9.9cm and 3.5cm) arc (-20:0:4cm and 15cm) -- cycle;
\draw [color=black!20] (0,0) -- (15,0);

\foreach \x in {2,13}
{\fill (\x-1.4,-0.2) rectangle (\x+1.4,-2);
\fill [color=white] (\x,-0.83) ellipse (1.3cm and 0.57cm);
\draw [line width=0.2cm] (\x+0.2,-0.15) .. controls (\x-1,-0.45) and (\x-1,-0.75) .. (\x,-0.85) .. controls (\x+1,-1.05) and (\x+1,-1.25) .. (\x-0.1,-1.55);
\fill [color=white] (\x-0.5,-0.2) rectangle (\x+0.5,-0.02);
\node [color=white] at (\x,-1.6) {\textbf{SCHMIDT}};};
%\draw [xslant=0.2,decorate,decoration={text along path,
%               text=|\Large|Holz-Schmidt OHG||}] (4.4,-0.7) .. controls (6.4,-1.3) and (8.6,-1.3) .. (10.6,-0.7);

\node at (7.5,-1.95) {\scriptsize{Lindenweg 2, 85467 Niederneuching}};
\node at (0.42,-2.7) [right] {\tiny{\underline{HOLZ-SCHMIDT OHG, 85467 NIEDERNEUCHING}}};

\node at (0.42,-3.8) [right] {\scriptsize{Exklusiv Möbel OHG}};
\node at (0.42,-4.2) [right] {\scriptsize{Bothengasse 3}};
\node at (0.42,-4.6) [right] {\scriptsize{83395 Freilassing}};

\node at (0.42,-5.75) [right] {\scriptsize{\textbf{Ihr Auftrag vom}}};
\node at (3.1,-5.75) [right] {\scriptsize{\textbf{Ihre Auftragsnummer}}};
\node at (7,-5.75) [right] {\scriptsize{\textbf{Sachbearbeiter}}};
\node at (10.,-5.75) [right] {\scriptsize{\textbf{Telefon}}};
\node at (12.5,-5.75) [right] {\scriptsize{\textbf{Datum}}};

\node at (7,-6.1) [right] {\scriptsize{Klaus Schreiber}};
\node at (10.,-6.1) [right] {\scriptsize{08654 4328-17}};
\node at (12.5,-6.1) [right] {\scriptsize{01.07.2009}};

\node at (0.42,-6.95) [right] {\scriptsize{\textbf{Sparen Sie Geld - kaufen Sie größere Mengen}}};

\node at (0.42,-7.7) [right] {\scriptsize{Sehr geehrte Damen, sehr geehrte Herren,}};

\node at (0.42,-8.5) [right] {\scriptsize{nach unseren Unterlagen beliefern wir Sie täglich mit Eichenholz zu einem Preis von}};
\node at (0.42,-8.85) [right] {\scriptsize{$\unit{512,00}{\text{€ pro }m^3}$.}};

\node at (0.42,-9.5) [right] {\scriptsize{Sparen Sie doch ganz einfach Zeit und Geld und kaufn Sie größere Mengen. Wenn Sie nur}};
\node at (0.42,-9.85) [right] {\scriptsize{einmal in der Woche bestellen, bieten wie Ihnen einen Preisnachlass von $20\%$.}};

\node at (0.42,-10.5) [right] {\scriptsize{Wir haben Ihre Bestellungen für die letzten zwölf Monate ausgewertet:}};

\node at (0.42,-11.2) [right] {\scriptsize{Durchschnittliche Bestellmenge je Woche:}};
\node at (0.42,-11.55) [right] {\scriptsize{Höchster Wochenbedarf:}};
\node at (0.42,-11.9) [right] {\scriptsize{Geringster Wochenbedarf:}};

\node at (7,-11.2) [right] {\scriptsize{$\unit{39}{m^3}$}};
\node at (7,-11.55) [right] {\scriptsize{$\unit{46}{m^3}$}};
\node at (7,-11.9) [right] {\scriptsize{$\unit{59}{m^3}$}};

\node at (0.42,-12.5) [right] {\scriptsize{Für Rückfragen stehe ich Ihnen gerne zur Verfügung.}};

\node at (0.42,-13.6) [right] {\scriptsize{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}};
\node at (0.42,-14.5) [right] {\large{\textsf{\textit{i.V. Klaus Schreiber}}}};

\node at (0.42,-15.5) [right] {\scriptsize{i. V. Klaus Schreiber}};
\node at (0.42,-15.85) [right] {\scriptsize{HOLZ-SCHMIDT OHG}};

\node at (0.42,-17.3) [right] {\scriptsize{UST-IDNR.: DE 134495980}};
\node at (5,-17.3) [right] {\scriptsize{Steuernummer: 114/589/31300}};
\node at (10,-17.3) [right] {\scriptsize{HR A 1755 Amtsgericht Erding}};

\node at (7.5,-1) {\Large{\textbf{Holz-Schmidt OHG}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have managed to create something!, so where is that code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As @HarishKumar already wrote: if you have already some basic code to work with, then show it! it's much easier to work with existing code than creating new code that might not be compatible with yours.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to a) generate the letter with `scrlttr2` and then b) just take a photo of it or use it with a tool like Blender?

Comment: Please make your code compile! I don't know which all packages need to be added to make it work. Also, take out packages which are *not* needed.

Comment: If you name the nodes at north east, north west, south east and south west of the letter (or place coordinates there), you could use the `fit` and `backgrounds` libraries to draw the letter and shadow behind the content.